Best Technique to Find 'The' BJT For Your Circuit?
I'm working on a small high voltage cascode stack class A amplifier. The bandwidth is primarily limited by BJT capacitance. I have a working prototype, as well as a well defined LTSpice simulation.
My question is with the 100's or 1000's of BJTs on the market, I struggle to find low capacitance versions. Even reading the datasheets of random high voltage (200-400 \$V_{ce}\$) ones, every manufacture has different methods of specifying capacitance.
The best methods I have so far that are far from ideal:

Use a transistor from similar design... (difficult for niche situations)
Ask a old BJT amplifier design expert... (few and far between)
Find models for a pile of transistors and simulate every one, assuming model is correct...

And if someone is going to mention JFET, I'm aware it may be a better solution.
Update - Adding Specifications:
The system is not high performance by modern standards. Sinusoidal amplification of 50-1000v output, signal generator input. I have a stack of 6 cascode BJTs to handle the below needs.

\$V_{out}\$ 50 - 1kV
\$R_{out}\$ < 100k
\$f_{sw}\$ DC - 50kHz (I could sacrifice DC for 1kHz min if needed)


Look for RF parts specifically?

Frustrating when high-voltage and high-bandwidth are pretty much mutually exclusive. Even more difficult if you need power transistors. Seems you've found a circuit arrangement (cascode stack) that helps maximize bandwidth. Be wary of models - some are optimized for a different application than yours.

I think a few more applications details should be posted.

@Andyaka - I left them out because I did not want to create a shopping question... I can add.

Do you mean Rout > 100k? Lesser includes anything to zero (or below, for that matter), which will be much more challenging to drive at these (or potentially any) voltages.

What value collector resistor (class A amplifier) are you expecting to use? It won't be a shopping question because it's about the process of choosing a transistor rather than asking for recommendations. What input signal level corresponds to 1000 volts out? Are we talking p-p output levels or RMS? Have you considered a transformer output circuit (given what you say about the LF)?

If it was easy anyone could do it.. if you're looking for examples, electrostatic speaker drivers might provide some ideas, but sometimes you just have to slog through the available parts and even breadboard some.

You can try search & sorting tools on manufaturers sites also like On-semi. In your case I would filter according Ft parameter. Since the amp works in linear area the Ft/2 frequency is ussually reachable if you drive the base “hard” enough. In switching apps a Ft/10 is a real number maybe.

Made with microcap v12
Note that UJC1210K is discontinued, it can be replaced with some equivalent.
With the use of SiC MOSFET, you can try something like this circuit.
The dissipated power is "big", around 100 W.
Probably can it be lower ...
Bandwidth is from ~ 50 Hz to more than 50 kHz.



